# My Android Studio not getting Open in MacOS?

Tags: android

[image]
Before Install it was showing like this.. Even i check System preference also. Kindly help me how to solve this problem

Comment: Have you installed it? Try to click on "Open"

Comment: @nageswaran this type of questions are unlikely to be welcome on stack overflow as it's too generic and can be solved by using any search engines. There are plenty of solutions about this already out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in your security preferences not to open applications from unidentified developers. When you try to open such application, it first show the alert dialog as you shared in your question. After that to run that application; next step is to go to your Preferences -> Security & Privacy as shared in the attached screenshot. [image: screenshot].

In the screenshot, you can see an Open Anyway button for your Android Studio application. Clicking on it will run the application.